# Multiple request synchronization to my rest API.

Tags: database, rest, concurrency

I have a server side rest api which updates a database table. The table looks like this

```
ID PubId DocUuid DocFamUuid CorrelationUuid
1   156   1A       2A            3A
```

The unique key is the ID and this server side API is generating a unique DocUuid for every request and it is generating a DocFamUuid and CorrelationUuid based on the PubId. So, every document with the same PubId will have the same DocFamUuid and same CorrelationUuid.

My question is I'm doing a look up to see if a specific pubId from the incoming requests exists in the db or not, if it does i choose the docFamUuid and correlationUuid of the first returned result else I generate both of them and save it to the db. Now, I have a clustered server environment where I can have two separate documents being picked up by 2 different servers and both start their thread of processing. So, what is the desired behavior in this situation ?
1. Request 1 comes in from Server 1 to the rest API, it has a pubId of 156, the service looks it up in the db.
2. Request 2 hits the database from Server 2 to the rest API, it too has pubId of 156 and it looks up the record does not exist in the db table. 
3. Request 1 creates a docFamUuid of 2A and correlationUuid of 3A and save it to the db
4. Request 2 has also now created a docFamUuid of 2B and correlationUuid of 3B and saved it to the db table. and now we have two different values

```
ID ID PubId DocUuid DocFamUuid CorrelationUuid
1   156   1A       2A            3A
2   156   1B       2B            3B
```

which is wrong because the desired result is:

```
ID ID PubId DocUuid DocFamUuid CorrelationUuid
1   156   1A       2A            3A
2   156   1B       2A            3A
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a concurrency problem than a rest problem.  You could add some sort of locking  mechanism around the database and check for existing pubIds immediately before the final insert.  If there is a conflict you could either resolve it server side somehow or return back a 409 CONFLICT from the rest service.

Comment: what kind of locking mechanism is possible ?

Comment: The available locking mechanisms really depends on what language your project is implemented in and what database is being used.